# Как получить сумму элементов побочной диагонали?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.container')

const elemGenerator = (tag, classN) => {
  if (!tag) return
  const element = document.createElement(tag)
  element.classN = classN ? classN : ''
  return element
}
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  return Math.floor(rand);
}
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    const element = elemGenerator('span', 'cl')
    cont.append(element.value = randomInteger(1, 50) + ' ');
  }
  cont.append(elemGenerator('br'))
}
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```

Comment: вы банально просто на листочке индексы нарисуйте и попробуйте подумать по какому закону они там написаны..... 02, 11 и 20. (ну или почитать про побочную диагональ в матрице)

Comment: Пронумеровать элементы так, что бы они были похожи на матрицу, допустим **0-1**. Далее циклом бежите, создаете нужный id элемента, допустим **1-1** и берете содержимое элемента из DOM, к примеру

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как получить сумму вот этих чисел?

Сумму элементов побочной диагонали можно получить вот так...

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.container')

const elemGenerator = (tag, classN) => {
  if (!tag) return
  const element = document.createElement(tag)
  element.classN = classN ? classN : ''
  return element
}
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  return Math.floor(rand);
}
// подготовка переменной
let sum = 0
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    const element = elemGenerator('span', 'cl')
    const v = randomInteger(1, 50)
    // очередной элемент побочной диагонали
    if (k == Math.abs(i - 2)) sum += v
    cont.append(element.value = v + ' ');
  }
  cont.append(elemGenerator('br'))
}
console.log(sum)
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```